# How to receiving several vcard via intent-filter and action.SEND_MULTIPLE

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts, intentfilter, vcf-vcard

I try to receive more than one contact in my app from the share feature in the Android Contact App but i receive only the first contact, I never receive `action` with `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`.

I have used https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive as inspiration.

AndroidManifest :

```
<activity android:name=".ShareActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/x-vcard" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/x-vcard" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

ShareActivity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
String type = intent.getType();

if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
    // My code always pass here because action is always equals to ACTION_SEND even with several contacts selectionned
    if ("text/x-vcard".equals(type)) {
        handleSendContact(intent);
    }
} else if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(action) && type != null) {
    if ("text/x-vcard".equals(type)) {
        handleSendMultiContact(intent);
    }
}

private void handleSendContact(Intent intent) {
    Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    // use uri to get lookupkey...
}

private void handleSendMultiContact(Intent intent) {
    ArrayList<Uri> contactUris = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    for (Uri uri : contactUris) {
        // use uri to get lookupkey...
    }
}
```

Sharing a single contact, all work perfectly, but when I select two or more contact my received action still is `ACTION_SEND` and not `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` and I receive only the first selected contact. My goal is to receive all contact selectionned in the Android Contact App.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short version :

`ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` is never used with Contacts/vCard sharing. Instead, `ACTION_SEND` is always used with data containing multiple contacts and the uri containing multi `LOOKUP_KEY` separated by `:`.

---

## Long version:

Sharing contact one :

```
content://com.android.contacts/contacts/as_multi_vcard/2345r1817-373F294D4F4329413151472F294F312F

BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:NAME_1;
TEL;WORK:039-999-9999
EMAIL;HOME:updated@home.fr
URL:www.home_updated.fr
END:VCARD
```

Sharing contact two :

```
content://com.android.contacts/contacts/as_multi_vcard/2345r1820-4D553943354B2F514F4D553943354B2F514F

BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:NAME_2;
TEL;WORK:039-999-9999
EMAIL;HOME:updated@home.fr
URL:www.home_updated.fr
END:VCARD
```

Sharing contacts one + two :

```
content://com.android.contacts/contacts/as_multi_vcard/2345r1817-373F294D4F4329413151472F294F312F%3A2345r1820-4D553943354B2F514F4D553943354B2F514F

BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:NAME_1;
TEL;WORK:039-999-9999
EMAIL;HOME:updated@home.fr
URL:www.home_updated.fr
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:NAME_2;
TEL;WORK:039-999-9999
EMAIL;HOME:updated@home.fr
URL:www.home_updated.fr
END:VCARD
```

As you can observe above, sharing both contacts results on an `Uri` with the two `LOOKUP_KEY` separated by `%3A` (colon in ASCII). I found the aosp code doing that in [PeopleActivity.java](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/06896b90ca0debd0db0e083e064e09f4b2a9d4e9/src/com/android/contacts/activities/PeopleActivity.java#L1271) for details.

So I can exploit multiple contact sharing with that chunk of code:

```
if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
    Log.d("type", "type: " + type);
    if (type.equals("text/x-vcard")) {
        handleSendContact(intent);
    }
}

void handleSendContact(Intent intent) {
    Uri contactUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    if (contactUri != null) {
        //  getLastPathSegment() decodes "%3A" to ":", so split must be done on colon
        String[] lookupKeys = contactUri.getLastPathSegment().split(":");
        for (String lookupKey : lookupKeys) {
            // Query contact with lookup key
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A single VCard file can contain one or more contacts, so I'm assuming the sending app is creating one VCard file for all selected contacts, which explains why `SEND` is more appropriate then `SEND_MULTIPLE`.

Check if your `handleSendContact` falsely assumes the VCard contains only one contact.

You can check the VCard being sent by sharing it via Gmail app instead, and send the file to yourself, and inspect it via some text editor. It should contain all selected contacts as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the anwer and yes you are right (a vcard contains multiple contacts if more than one is selected), the problem is that I need to have one lookupkey per contact to query the Contacts database (vcard's data isn't enough).